# Multiplayer: 2 player on separate consoles plus 2 on split screen

Tags: ps3, borderlands

Is it possible to play Borderlands in a setup where two players (running split screen) join a game with 1 or 2 other players (the later running on different PS3s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (October 2010), there is no support for 2 people running Splitscreen multiplayer to play with others online or via system link (locally). Gearbox has stated that it is due to technical limitation, and they do not plan on patching it in the future. On their official forums, there are 2 petition threads, one for [System Link Support](http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=76779&highlight=splitscreen+experience+online) and one for [Online Support](http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=72033&highlight=splitscreen+experience+online) that you can keep an eye on. In the System Link Support thread, you can see a response from Gearbox stating the following:

> Thank you for writing Gearbox with your comments! Unfortunately, it is a technical limitation, not a design choice, that prevents us from bringing a split-screen experience online in any way - even via local network. Split-screen support was added after many network design decisions and implementations were already made and it's simply not possible for us to rewrite and update.
>
> We're interested in improving the Borderlands experience for players, and appreciate you taking the time to let us know your concerns. You can track the status of known issues and find information about updates to Borderlands on our community forums: http://gbxforums.gearboxsoftware.com...ad.php?t=77748
>
> Thank you again for your comments, and we hope you enjoy your adventures in Pandora!
>
> Regards,
>   Gearbox Software Support

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to have online split screen play in Borderlands:

[Borderlands: LAN & Online Split-Screen Support Not Coming](http://gamerant.com/borderlands-lan-system-link-splitscreen-support-coming-zac-2214/)

The link refers to the XBox 360 version but the PS3 is the same.

There are unfortunately very few games that allow multiple local players to go online - LittleBigPlanet and ModNation Racers are two that come to mind for the PS3.